# What is an "external node" of a "magic" 3-gon ring?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I want to solve Project Euler's [problem #68](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=68) in C#, but I've so far not understood the question clearly. What does **external node** mean in this problem statement?

> Consider the following "magic" 3-gon ring, filled with the numbers 1
>   to 6, and each line adding to nine.
>
> ```
>    4
>     \
>      3
>     / \
>    1 - 2 - 6
>   /
>  5
> ```
>
> Working **clockwise**, and starting from the group of three with the
>   numerically lowest external node (4,3,2 in this example), each
>   solution can be described uniquely. For example, the above solution
>   can be described by the set: 4,3,2; 6,2,1; 5,1,3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'External node' is a node not included in the inner triangle (pentagon). On the first picture, 4, 5 and 6 are external nodes.
Regarding 'helping to understand the question', what other parts confuse you?

**edit**
In the first sentence it says 'each line adding to nine', 9 here is the total. You can calculate the 'total' of each solution by summing up numbers in any of 3 lines.

Comment: I also don't understand what they mean with  the line "It is possible to complete the ring with four different totals: 9, 10, 11, and 12.".

Comment: What that means is that in the example given, all of the lines of three circles have numbers which total 9. However, it is also possible to choose different numbers, and make all of those lines add up to 10, 11, or 12 as well.

Answer (score 1):

@Kristo Aun: Think of the '4,3,2; 6,2,1; 5,1,3' > '4,2,3; 5,3,1; 6,1,2' as numbers, which means 432621513 > 423531612. The numbers come from a single line in any order, though you need to start clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

In the task, they say "By concatenating each group it is possible to form 9-digit strings; the maximum string for a 3-gon ring is 432621513."

What is meant by 'maximum'? How come '4,3,2; 6,2,1; 5,1,3' > '4,2,3; 5,3,1; 6,1,2'? It certainly doesn't make sense in terms of set theory...